# How to pass the data from child components to parent data without using eventemitters in angular7?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular7

I need to get the data from child components oninit only. How to get that? Is it Possible or not?

When visiting the child component, parent components needs to print the name of that child component. How to do that ?

Comment: Just use an event emitter ?

Comment: You can pass a method reference to child in `@Input` property and call it in `ngOnInit`. But why?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is using [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

Add @ViewChild in your parent component:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  ...
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
  ...
```

Now on parent's `ngOnInit` you will have access to your child component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // this.child - will give you access to your child component
}
```

> Check this [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchild-so54435853) to see this in action